# Inner Products of Elements in Spherical Cap

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, spherical-geometry

I am interested in understanding what is the lowerbound on the inner products of two elements of a sphere. Based on my intuition in dimension 2, I come up with the following conjecture. I appreciate any comments. Here is the formal statement:

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $S^{(d-1)}$ denote the sphere in dimension $\mathbb{R}^d$. For a fixed $v \in S^{(d-1)}$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi/2)$, let
$$
C_{\theta,v} = \{x \in S^{(d-1)}: \langle x,v \rangle \geq \cos(\theta) \}.
$$

**Conjecture**
Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two arbitrary elements of $C_{\theta,v}$. Is it correct that
$$
\langle x_1,x_2  \rangle \geq \cos(2\theta).
$$

Comment: This is an elementary problem. Mathematics Stack Exchange wold be a better forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this follows immediately from the triangle inequality on the sphere -- cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924742/prove-the-triangle-inequality-on-the-sphere-s2-in-mathbbr3) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).